# Select more than 1 mysql field with COUNT statement

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to select records with the same session_id and the following mysql statement works:

```
SELECT session_id, COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences
FROM my_table
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

However I am able to access only session_id, not any ofther field. I tried something like:

```
SELECT session_id, other_filed COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences
FROM my_table
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

but it doesnt work. Also tried *, but also doesnt work:

```
SELECT * COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences
FROM my_table
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Looks like you missed a `,` before `COUNT`.

Comment: There's a missing comma after _other_filed_. However, because of the group by it will always have only one row returned per session_id

Comment: Ah, I see - since the other fields are different it cannot return one value...

Comment: Post the output off  `SHOW CREATE TABLE [your_table]` ... And using columns in SELECT what are not used in the GROUP BY is asking for trouble because your are using GROUP BY wrong in query 2 and query 3... And if you want to select double (or more) session id your query should be something like this.. `SELECT session_id, COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences FROM my_table GROUP BY session_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` or `SELECT session_id, COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences FROM my_table GROUP BY session_id HAVING NumOccurrences >= 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query generates an aggregate result set, and you're trying to display a detail value (a value from the raw table, not the aggregate) at the same time.

So if you try this you will get something. [`ANY_VALUE()` tells MySQL explicitly to choose some single value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) of `other_field` for each value of `session_id`.

```
SELECT COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences,
       ANY_VALUE(other_field)
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY session_id
```

Be careful with [the `ANY_VALUE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value): it really should be called `SURPRISE_ME()`. It returns the value of some row in the `GROUP BY` group. Which row it returns is entirely up to the MySQL server. It isn't a random value, it's worse than that. It returns the same value every time you run the query, until it doesn't.  It can change, or not, when a table grows or shrinks, or when the server has more or less RAM, or when the server version changes, or when Mars is in retrograde, whatever that means. You have been warned.

You could also do

```
SELECT COUNT(session_id) AS NumOccurrences,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT other_field ORDER BY other_field)
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY session_id
```

to get a list of values for `other_field`.

Also, `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` is redundant. There's no way for a particular `session_id` value to appear in your result set unless it appears in at least one row of your table.